# Does the Infestation cantrip cause the target to provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, opportunity-attack, unearthed-arcana, forced-movement

*Infestation* is one of the new cantrips from *Unearthed Arcana: Starter Spells*. Here is the relevant text

> The target must succeed on a
>   Constitution saving throw or take 1d6 piercing
>   damage. If the target takes any of that damage,
>   **the target moves 5 feet in a random direction**.
>   Roll a d8 for the direction...

Does the target's movement here provoke opportunity attacks from any of my adjacent allies?

Comment: This spell has now been officially released in Xanathar's Guide to Everything and can be found on DnDBeyond [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/infestation).

Comment: Related: [Can I trigger an Opportunity Attack by forcing an opponent to move out of my reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120959/can-i-trigger-an-opportunity-attack-by-forcing-an-opponent-to-move-out-of-my-rea)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This spell ended up printed in Xanathar's Guide to Everything, with clarifying language.

> This movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks, and if the direction rolled is blocked, the target doesn’t move.

I don't believe it was ever intended to provoke AoO.

Answer (score 19):

As written, this doesn't trigger opportunity attacks.

> You
>   also
>   don’t
>   provoke
>   an
>   opportunity
>   attack
>   when
>   you
>   teleport
>   or
>   when
>   someone
>   or
>   something
>   moves
>   you
>   without
>   using
>   your
>   movement,
>   action,
>   or
>   reaction.

Since the spell doesn't use the target's movement, action or reaction, it won't provoke opportunity attacks.

That said, this is a very odd spell. With Unearthed Arcana, you have to remember the disclaimer:

> These game mechanics are in draft form, usable in your campaign but not refined by design iterations or full game development and editing.

Why do I think it's odd? Well, lots of spells move a target around without using their movement, action, or reaction. But this spell says that "the target moves", not that they are moved. This suggests that it *might* be intended to use their movement, or possibly a reaction, similar to spells like *Dissonant Whispers* or *Confusion*.

So while, in its current form, the spell doesn't provoke opportunity attacks, between its current form and its published form (if it ever gets published), it may well be changed slightly so that it does.

Comment: This spell has now been released officially in XGE and answers the question explicitly: "...moves 5 feet in a random direction if it can move and its speed is at least 5 feet. Roll a d4 for the direction... This movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks, and if the direction rolled is blocked, the target doesn’t move."

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Sure, but the question was about the UA version. And please don't close every question involving forced movement and opportunity attacks as a dupe of yours. Your question is very general, and that's fine, but it doesn't answer this one at all.

Comment: I just thought it night be a helpful thing to note for future searchers but it's fine either way. Also, I agree the question is different. That would, in fact, be the reason why I did not close this one at all. I also didn't close nearly every question about the subject due to cases like this only the ones that were clearly duplicates.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose [You did, though?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/99340/revisions)

Comment: oh sorry. I assumed I didn't because it wasn't closed. I actually disagree that it is not a duplicate but I don't think it matters that much honestly.